Angular MatSelect and horizontal scroll problem
As you can see in the stackblitz exemple, the vanilla html select works fine in horizontal scrollable div, but not the mat-select (or also material menu).
To reproduce, scroll to left and click on a select, this will scroll to right on click, so you can't change selected option on firsts selects.
I've opened an issue about this problem, but I do not get answers.
So I'm asking here if someone has already encountered this problem, or if you have any idea to solve this.

You are having the below code, which sets the scroll left position, that is causing this weird bug, since it's firing on every click of the view. It's not a problem with the Angular Material select.
You can instead set it to ngAfterViewInit, this seems to solve the issue.
site-breadcrumb.component.ts
Before:
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  // this.breadcrumbContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft =
  //   this.breadcrumbContainer.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
}

After:
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.breadcrumbContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft =
    this.breadcrumbContainer.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
}


Stackblitz Demo
Sample code where it works fine

Hi, thank you for your answer ! I've removed the code, I can't remember why I have writed this... ^^'
